# no result are found - haystack django whoosh

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

I have a huge problem!

I am using haystack and whoosh and django. I am sure I've done everything that is required to be done to make it works according to the documentation.

BUT!!!! results of searching are: "no results found" all the time. But if symbols I put into the form are spaces, every objects I've indexed are printed

Details:

In my search_indexes.py I have:

```
from haystack.indexes import *
from haystack import site
from aias.models import Uspd

class UspdIndex(SearchIndex):
    text   = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    serial = CharField(model_attr = 'serial')
    type_id = IntegerField(model_attr = 'type_id')
    name   = CharField(model_attr = 'name')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Uspd.objects.all()                                                                                       
site.register(Uspd, UspdIndex)
```

I've created template in folder `folder_where_I_have_templates/search/indexes/name_of_my_applcation` and printed

```
{{ object.type_id }}
{{ object.name }}
{{ object.serial }}
```

there.

By the way I did

```
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()
>>> sqs.count()
```

And result was 0
What the hell is going on????

Help me please!

Comment: did you rebuild search index? (`manage.py rebuild_index`)

Comment: Yes. I did it. I have also tried manage.py update_index and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what the search document is called. It should be: uspd_text.txt

The doco said:

**You’ll need to create a new template inside your template directory called search/indexes/myapp/note_text.txt  and place the following inside**